# Getting date value in a computed field of a data table

Tags: xpages

I can not believe how simple this should be but it is just not working for me.  I have a data table.   I have a computed field for one of the columns of that data table.

```
<xp:text escape="true" id="computedField1">
<xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:var doc:NotesDocument = database.getDocumentByUNID(rowData);return doc.getItemValueDateTimeArray("FormCreated")[0];}]]></xp:this.value>    
<xp:this.converter><xp:convertDateTime type="both" dateStyle="short"timeStyle="short"></xp:convertDateTime></xp:this.converter>
</xp:text>
```

This does not display a value for the date field.  If I prepend doc.getItemValueDateTimeArray("FormCreated")[0]  with "0" +   to make it

```
"" + doc.getItemValueDateTimeArray("FormCreated")[0]
```

Then the date shows but not in the format I have selected for the field.  I am guessing the "" + is converting the date to a string.  How do I display this date / time in the format that I want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use SimpleDateFormat like this

```
var dt:NotesDateTime=doc.getItemValueDateTimeArray("FormCreated")[0]
var jdate=dt.toJavaDate()
var Pattern = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("Date pattern you want to display");
var retstring=Pattern.format( jdate )
dt.recycle()
```

The info on the pattern format can be found here
[SimpleDateFormat Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)